# NumberFormatException when checking if Integer is null

Tags: java

I am trying to make the user only enter a non-negative number and if the user closes the dialog the program should terminate.

```
        Integer num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive number"));
    if (num == null)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if (num < 0)
    {
        num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive number"));
    }
```

This code works if num is type String but not when I changed it to integer.
I get a NumberFormatException when I try to run it and the code in the if statment is dead code.

Comment: It is *impossible* for `num` to be null, because `Integer.parseInt()` returns a *primitive* `int` value, and those cannot be null, and the compiler auto-boxes that into an `Integer` for you. Why would you think that `parseInt()` would return null if input is bad? The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) is quite explicit in what will happen for bad input: *Throws `NumberFormatException` if the string does not contain a parsable integer.*

Comment: And that's what causing the NFE. So how do I fix it?

Comment: [Catch the exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).

Comment: When type is String, you should use `compareTo` and not use smaller then operations (The result is internationalization dependent: `A < 0` might be true, while `a < 0` might be false (Comparing strings, not integers, so these comparissons are valid)).

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen What code are you looking at? `num` is `Integer`, not `String`. Besides, using `<` with a `String` is a compile error.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Comparing strings with >, < or the other relations is a compile-time error in java.

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` doesn't return null if passed a null/invalid string, it throws an exception, which you need to catch.

```
int num;
for (;;) {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive number");
    if (input == null) System.exit(0);

    try {
        num = Integer.parseInt(input);
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the function `showInputDialog` returns an empty string if exited or if the input was nothing so for fixing it you can check the input if it's empty look at this code:

```
num = (str.equals(""))?null:Integer.parseInt(str);
```

it's better to use a `do{}while();` loop to get a more efficient code example:

```
    String str;
    Integer num;
    do{
        str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a positive number");
        num = (str.equals(""))?null:Integer.parseInt(str);
        if(num == null){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }while(num<0);
```

Answer (score 0):

NFE - indicates that your string is not a number so you need to catch an error and make decision of what to do in case of unsuitable string, eg.

```
  try {
        if (Integer.parseInt("-123") < 0) {
            // do job
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // string is not a number
        // set value to default, log error, return error to users view
        System.exit(9);
    }
```